# Python line-plane collision detection

Tags: python, math, collision-detection, intersection

I need to work out whether a line segment will intersect a face of a 3D polygon (so a section of a plane confined by 4 points). Are there any well known python libraries that I could use? If not, how should I go about this?

I've tried looking at line-plane intersection equations but they seem over complicated as I only need to know **if** it will intersect, not find the point of intersection.

Sorry if this question has been asked before! Thanks

Comment: The question isn't clear, is this to intersect the polygon defined by 4 points, or the plane defined by said polygon. (title and content differ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do this that's simpler than the obvious one:

1. find the infinite plan that contains your polygon
2. determine the point where the line intersects that plane
3. determine whether this point is within the polygon

All but the very rare line will intersect the infinite plan somewhere, so the question isn't "does it intersect the plane", but "where"?

Each step in the above will be about as simple as a 3D geometry question can get, but still involve many the 3D mathematical tools (vectors, matrices, etc).  There are lots of descriptions about how to do them, and I recommend that you search around for one that's presented at a level and in a notation that you're comfortable with.  For example, for the line (infinite) plane intersection you could look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93plane_intersection).